# Is it possible to recognize a face with only with eyes?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any way to recognize a face only with an eyes other than Haarcascade_eyes.XML model?I tried with this but it failed to recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is model named PCN you can try it. Other than that you can also use dlib.

Comment: Thank you, will try that Well I want to recognize a person when he is on facemask .So when the person is on facemask only feature which I get is his eyes so I tried with haarcascade-eye.XML but it fail to recognize .
for e.g. I want to recognize Barak Obama I have collected dataset of him then I use haarcascade_eye.xml model

Comment: Haarcascade-eye is only for detection. For recognition you will need a different algorithm like deep neural network classifier